# Redshift how to subtract the number of minutes from two different date columns

Tags: amazon-redshift

I would like to subtract two date columns and get the difference in minutes. Based on the table below, we can see that a notification has an ideal_date of 11/29 1pm and we noticed that the actual_date was sent on 12/30 1pm that means that it took 24 hours for the notification to be sent, meaning it took 1440 minutes for the notification to be sent out.
I tried the following query but I'm not getting what I need.

```
select n.ideal_date,
       n.actual_date,
abs(date_part(minute,n.ideal_date) - date_part(minute,n.actual_date)) as minutes
from table_date n
```

| id | ideal_date | actual_date | minutes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 58 | 12/29/2021,1:00pm | 12/30/2021, 1:00pm | 1440 mins |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want DATEDIFF().  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html

```
select n.ideal_date,
       n.actual_date,
       abs(DATEDIFF(minute,n.ideal_date,n.actual_date)) as minutes
from table_date n
```